Having an issue with server-sided overhead healthbar gui in Roblox
So when I run the game, the code does nothing. I want it to be above every player's head and I want all the players to have the ability to see one another's health
Here is the code:
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    Player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Character)
local Bar = game.ServerStorage:WaitForChild("Gui").HealthHolder.HealthBar
local Holder = script.Parent
local hp = 100
local mps = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")

local function update_bar()
    Bar:TweenSizeAndPosition(UDim2.new(hp/100,0,1,0), UDim2.new(0,0,0,0), "Out", "Linear", 0.15, true)
    if mps:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(Player.UserId, 216944514) then
        Bar:TweenSizeAndPosition(UDim2.new(hp/200,0,1,0), UDim2.new(0,0,0,0), "Out", "Linear", 0.15, true)
    end
end


local function update_char(char)
    char:WaitForChild("Humanoid"):GetPropertyChangedSignal("Health"):Connect(function()
        hp = char.Humanoid.Health
        update_bar()
    end)
end

update_bar()
update_char(Character)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(c)
    Character = c
    update_char(c)
    hp = 100
    update_bar()
    end)
    end)
    end)
end)

